# Do SAML 2.0 Attribute Statements have a size limit?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

As the title says, I'm wondering if SAML 2.0 Attribute Statements have a definite size limit? Or does the limit vary from IDP to IDP? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as the Response is being sent via a `POST` transaction, or being retrieved via `Attribute Query`, there's no limit on sizing of the Response and its various Attribute statements. With the `Redirect` binding (uncommon for Responses for security reasons), the use of large Attributes will be governed by any limits that browsers may impose on size of the supported URL (as an example, I believe IE11 still has an 8K character limit on the length of the URL).